# libpcap static linking in Centos 6.x

Tags: centos, static-linking, libpcap

I downloaded the Libpcap-1.7.4 library . when i want to run libpcap.o and libpcap.so.1.7.4, the following errors appear:

```
[root@localhost libpcap-1.7.4]# ./libpcap.a
./libpcap.a: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./libpcap.a: line 1: `!<arch>'
[root@localhost libpcap-1.7.4]# ./libpcap.so.1.7.4 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Could you give me some advice about what I should do?

OS: Centos 6.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you give me some advice about what I should do?

Not try to run libpcap - it's a library, not a program, so you can't run it, you can only link a program with it.

What you need to do is link a program with it, and then run the *program*.

For example, if you have a C source file named `small_sniffer.c`, and you want to compile it and link it with libpcap, try

```
gcc -o small_sniffer small_sniffer.c -lpcap
```

for dynamic linking and

```
gcc -static -o small_sniffer small_sniffer.c -lpcap
```

to link *entirely* statically

Comment: If you want to ONLY static link libpcap, this works: gcc -o sniffer main.c /usr/lib/libpcap.a